# Blank custom metadata when uploading file to AWS S3 using iOS SDK

Tags: ios, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, metadata, aws-sdk

I'm uploading a file to S3 from iOS using `AWSS3TransferUtility` and trying to set come custom metadata on the file. I'm testing it using the metadata key `X-Amz-Meta-uploadParameters` and the value "Test".

It appears correctly in the request headers:

```
... &X-Amz-Expires=2999&X-Amz-Meta-uploadParameters=Test&X-Amz-Security-Token= ...
```

Something is clearly happening, since after upload the key `uploadparameters` does appear in the object's properties in the S3 console, but with a blank value. To double-check I used `s3api --head-object` from the CLI and here's what's returned:

```
{
    "AcceptRanges": "bytes",
    "LastModified": "Thu, 16 Mar 2017 08:04:41 GMT",
    "ContentLength": 1331730,
    "ETag": "\"[hex data here]\"",
    "ContentType": "image/jpeg",
    "Metadata": {
        "uploadparameters": ""
    }
}
```

Here's how I'm setting the value up for the `AWSS3TransferUtilityUploadExpression`:

```
        let params = [
            "X-Amz-Meta-uploadParameters": "Test"
        ]

        //Copy the custom Meta information into the expression
        for (key, value) in params {
            expression.setValue(value, forRequestParameter: key)
        }
```

Having played around with all kinds of variations I'm still no closer to setting actual metadata. What am I missing here?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Fixed. After posting this question I continued tweaking things in frustration and stumbled across the answer.

**Altering the key to all lower case** is the magic twist, i.e. `x-amz-meta-uploadparameters` rather than `X-Amz-Meta-uploadParameters`. Incidentally, it also fails with `X-Amz-Meta-uploadparameters`.

Comment: That smells very much like a bug.

Comment: it is documented. it has to be lower case